# Мне нужно при клике на любую из 4 картинок присвоить класс одному блоку ( JavaScript, HTML )

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста, в JS совсем не силен, у меня есть 4 картинки с одинаковыми классами и div блок, который находится далеко в дереве элементов от картинок. При нажатии на любую картинку из четырех нужно добавлять класс блоку. Знаю как сделать для одной картинки. А как сделать так, чтобы любая из 4 при клике добавляла класс ? Примерно:

```
..  
  ..
    <img class='image-btn'>
    <img class='image-btn'>
    <img class='image-btn'>
    <img class='image-btn'>
  ..
..
  ..
    ..
      <div class='block _displaynone'></div>
```

JS который я писал для одной картинки (не работает для 3 остальных):

```
const imageBtn = document.querySelector('.image-btn')

imageBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    block.classList.add('_displaynone');
});
```

Comment: [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

> JS который я писал для одной картинки (не работает для 3 остальных)

Используй делегирование событий https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

```js
image.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('image-btn')) return
  document.querySelector('.block').classList.add('_displaynone')
})
```

```css
.image-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.block {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.block._displaynone {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='image'>
  <img class='image-btn' />
  <img class='image-btn' />
  <img class='image-btn' />
  <img class='image-btn' />
</div>
<div class='block'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const imageBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".image-btn")
const divBlock = document.querySelector('.block')
imageBtns.forEach(function (imageBtn) {
    imageBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        divBlock.classList.add('_displaynone')
    })
})
```